# Spring session-scoped bean with construtor argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In Spring I have bean that should not be instantiated without a constructor argument which depend on user input. what is the correct way to instantiate the SessionScoped bean in a controller or another Singleton-Scopped bean  ?

```
public class SingletonScoped{
    ...
}

public class SessionScoped{
    @Autowired
        SingletonScoped singletonScopped;

    private SessionScoped(){
    }

    public SessionScoped(Object userInput){

    }

}

 public class AnotherSingletonScoped{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

basically i should add spring argument in serverlet-context.xml then u can passing argument here. A more detail u can see in this post http://chiase.azurewebsites.net/?p=171

Comment: Please add more detail. This answer is really poor.

Comment: According to [the guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), you should not post links without posting relevant content - the link may break, and then this answer will no longer help users.